# multithreadin on gui in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

i'm working on a project that contains multithreading on GUI
here's my code
in my form.cs file i use this code

```
    delegate void voidstringfunction(System.Drawing.Image x);

    public void ShowImage(System.Drawing.Image x)
    {

        if (pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
            pictureBox1.Invoke(new voidstringfunction(ShowImage), x);

        pictureBox1.Image = x;
        pictureBox1.Update();

    }

    public void ThreadFunc(){
        SGSserverForm form2 = (SGSserverForm)(Application.OpenForms[0]);
        form2.ShowImage(tempImage);
    }
    //this event is running too
    void videoSource_NewFrameEvent(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        pictureBox5.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => pictureBox5.Image = tempIm));
    }
```

when i start thread, in program.cs file i get this exception "Object is currently in use elsewhere."
on line that contains

```
sgsClientForm.ShowDialog();
```

what's the problem?
thanks everyone

Comment: put try catch in thread and functions you have used and try to locate the exact location of the problem. Its hard to figure out the problem as you have not provided enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check whether you need to invoke, and `Invoke` if so. However, after invoking, you continue the method, performing the operation on the "non-GUI" thread anyway. Try this:

```
public void ShowImage(System.Drawing.Image x)
{
    if (pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invoke(new voidstringfunction(ShowImage), x);
        return;
    }

    pictureBox1.Image = x;
    pictureBox1.Update();
}
```

Comment: Right sorry my bad. Going to delete my comment as it is not helping anyone